# How do you extend swap space if swap space is being used

Tags: swap

I have a swap disk (non-LVM) of 64GB. The swap space is currently being used and there is only 8GB free. I have increased the swap disk itself to 128GB. How would I extend the swap space from 64GB to use the rest of the disk space of 128GB without effecting anything currently using the swap space.

Comment: I would try to find out why or what is using so much swap instead. That's not normal.

Comment: You can have multiple swaps. Undo the expansion (back to 64GB) and create another 64GB swap. Read `man mkswap swapon fallocate`.

Comment: Ubuntu can use multiple swaps on multiple disks. If you boot and work from a Live/Persistent USB, you can use Disks to turn swap off. I think I recall that you can turn swap off even from the main OS and edit it's partition/file.